# Remove decimal from ordered <ol> list via CSS?

Tags: css, html-lists

I assume the answer is "no," but I thought I'd throw the question out there to all you CSS ninjas, since it has cropped up before, and when you're digging through code that involves a whole team, the happiest answer isn't always "well, just rework the code."

Given an ordered list:

```
<ol>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

Is it possible to remove the decimal points but retain numbering via JUST CSS, no javascript hackery, etc.?  My gut and experience says "absolutely not," but I know there are some pretty creative types out there, and I wonder if there's something I haven't considered yet.

**Update**

Possible text example, as requested:

Convert ordered list that looks like this:

```
1. [...content...]
2. [...content...]
3. [...content...]
```

To something like this:

```
1 [...content...]
2 [...content...]
3 [...content...]
```

All with CSS wizardy, no javascript.  Again, I realize this might be impossible, but ya just never know, do ya.

Comment: Can you give a textual example of what you're trying to achieve? Like "Change 1.1 Apple, 1.2 Orange to 1 Apple, 2 Orange" etc.?

Comment: I'd like to keep this open longer.  While I like @reisio's answer, it doesn't work in many circumstances, for example, when text wraps.  If I don't get another solid answer within a reasonable wait, I'll close it out.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works in Firefox 3.6.6 and Chrome 6, but not in IE7 or IE8 (no suprise there).

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counter(item) " "; counter-increment: item }
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#scope

Comment: It would be nice to see something a little more backward compatible, but this is pretty darn smart, and forward looking awesome.

Answer (score 1):

For a low-tech but highly cross-browser compatible solution, you can use a background image with vertically stacked numbers applied to the `ol`; just specify a `line-height` to be sure it all aligns.

Comment: Not sure I follow the logic here entirely.  Can you expound on this?

Comment: Wow -- that's pretty smart -- it has it's limitations, but *definitely* can work with the right constraints.